# SQL Count Condicional

Tags: sql

tenho a seguinte tabela

```
+----------+----------+
|   data   |    valor |
+----------+----------+
| 16/05/15 |        1 |
| 16/05/15 |        0 |
| 16/05/15 |        1 |
| 16/05/15 |        0 |
| 17/05/15 |        2 |
| 17/05/15 |        1 |
| 17/05/15 |        1 |
| 17/05/15 |        0 |
| 18/05/15 |        2 |
| 18/05/15 |        2 |
| 18/05/15 |        1 |
| 18/05/15 |        0 |
| 19/05/15 |        2 |
| 19/05/15 |        2 |
| 19/05/15 |        2 |
| 19/05/15 |        2 |
+----------+----------+
```

Preciso fazer um sql que conte a quantidade de 0, 1 e 2, porém estou conseguindo fazer somente com sql separado, como posso fazer um unico select?

```sql
SELECT data, COUNT(valor) 
FROM treatment_output 
WHERE valor = 0 
GROUP BY data ORDER BY data
```

Comment: Você que contar a quantidade desses 3 números (valor) ? só são esses ?  é separado por Data ? ou vai se uma coluna para cada?

Comment: Cara, voce esteve tao perto... SELECT data, COUNT(valor) 
FROM treatment_output 
--WHERE valor = 0 
GROUP BY data,valor ORDER BY data

Comment: por que o "Condicional"?

Comment: Eu preciso que valor=0, 1 e 2 sejam contado e criados novas colunas para cada um deles.

Answer (score 4):

Tu vai precisar selecionar todos os registros, agrupar por valor e usar a função de agregação `COUNT`.

Assim o `COUNT` fará a contagem de registros de cada grupo separado.

```sql
SELECT 
    data,
    valor, 
    COUNT(valor) as quantidade
FROM treatment_output
GROUP BY data, valor ORDER BY valor
```

*EDIT*: adicionado o campo `data` no `GROUP BY`. A pergunta não esclarece que quer agrupamento por data.

Comment: Poderiam pelo menos comentar porque minha resposta foi ruim para que eu melhore?

Comment: Vea abaixo, voce so esqueceu de incluir a data no groupby

Comment: Desisto, a pergunta fala especificamente que ele quer um sql que **conte a quantidade de 0, 1 e 2**... ele não fala em momento nenhum sobre data...

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT data, COUNT(valor) 
FROM treatment_output 
--WHERE valor = 0 
GROUP BY data,valor ORDER BY data
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja assim:

```
select count(*), valor from treatment_output
group by valor
```

Comment: tem um where perdido ai na consulta..

Comment: kkkk. Eu havia copiado a clausula where valor = 0 dele e não a retirei completamente.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT QTD,COUNT(*) Ocorrencias
From
(
SELECT data, COUNT(valor) QTD
FROM treatment_output 
WHERE valor = 0
GROUP BY data 
) VIRTUAL
Group by QTD
```